# How to I pass extra parameters to onExpansionChanged in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that creates x amount of ExpansionTiles depending on how many items there are in a list. When a tile gets expanded, I want to be able to find out which one has been expanded so that I can change an icon on the page to something.
I was thinking that I could send the ID to the onExpansionChanged function - but I can't get that to work as I also need the bool that it sends that says if it is expanding/collapsing.
Is there a way I can send both the bool and the ID?
My current code:

```
ExpansionTile(
      leading: Icon(expansionIcon),
      title: Text("name"),
      children: [
        Text('1'),
        Text('2')
      ],
      trailing: SizedBox.shrink(),
      onExpansionChanged: _onExpansion,
    );
_onExpansion(bool expanding){
      setState(() {
        if (expanding){
            --do something --
        }else{
            --do something --
        }
      });
  }
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
      onExpansionChanged: _onExpansion(id),

_onExpansion(bool expanding, int id){
      setState(() {
        if (expanding){
            --do something with id --
        }else{
            --do something with id--
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by calling it like this

```
onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) => _onExpansion(expanding, index),
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling your function this way onExpansionChanged: (){_onExpansion(id);}

```
ExpansionTile(
      leading: Icon(expansionIcon),
      title: Text("name"),
      children: [
        Text('1'),
        Text('2')
      ],
      trailing: SizedBox.shrink(),
      onExpansionChanged: (){_onExpansion(id);},
    );
```